# How can I install vanilla Android on the Kindle Fire?

Tags: custom-roms, amazon-kindle-fire, vanilla-android

I just received my Amazon Kindle Fire and since I am not located within the USA I can't use most of services provided Amazon. So I think the best thing for me would be to install a vanilla (custom) Android ROM.

**How can I install vanilla Android on the Kindle Fire?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most stable option at this point is to use CyanogenMod. You can get it onto your Fire by doing the following:

## Root and Custom Recovery

On Windows, you can use the [Kindle Fire Utility](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1399889) to root the Kindle Fire and install Team Win's recovery (TWRP). It's extremely straightforward, and should even set up the Google drivers for you. The whole process is done via a command-line numeric menu.

On non-Windows OSes (of if you just prefer it) you can manually root with [BurritoRoot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410223). It's also fairly painless. You'll then need to set up `adb` on your OS, and install TWRP, which can be done by following [this guide](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12343-how-to-install-twrp-20-linux/) on RootzWiki. The gist of it is that you need to reboot into fastboot and then flash the recovery image, which should be:

```
user@linux ~ $ adb shell
$ su
# idme bootmode 4002
# reboot
user@linux ~ $ fastboot -i 0x1949 boot path-to-twrp.img
user@linux ~ $ fastboot oem idme bootmode 4000  <-- After auto-reboot
user@linux ~ $ fastboot reboot
```

Or something along those lines.

## Flashing CyanogenMod

This works just like any other recovery system, really. Just grab CyanogenMod  and put it onto your `/sdcard` partition. Reboot into TWRP by powering off the device, then pressing/holding the power button at the FIREFIREFIRE bootloader (installed with the TWRP image), and use TWRP to select and flash the CM zip.

### Cyanongenmod for Kindle Fire

- [CM10 / Jelly Bean](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1591850)
- [Ice Cream Sandwich](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1411895)

Comment: @Flow I know that you accepted the answer, but can you confirm that you actually did this and it worked with no problems?

Comment: Do you know if the Kindle Fire will support Android 5? Or even 6? And if the method is still the same?

Comment: @Mawg The first gen Kindle Fire? I would doubt it, but I have no idea.

Comment: The latest generation.

Comment: @Mawg These instructions probably won't have any relevance on the latest generation; they were written for the first gen version. You'll most likely need to find new instructions for that device (or post a new question).