# How to install vanilla Android OS on Kindle Fire?

Tags: rom, amazon-kindle-fire, vanilla-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install vanilla Android on the Kindle Fire?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/how-can-i-install-vanilla-android-on-the-kindle-fire)

I have a Kindle Fire device and I want to install the vanilla Android OS on it.

Please help me how to flush out the original ROM and how to install new vanilla Android on it.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery currently installed, or the stock one? Also, do you really mean "stock" in the sense that you want the original ROM that came with the Fire, or do you actually want a "vanilla" (unmodified) Android install?

Comment: I actually want vanilla(unmodified)android I have the Custom Os on my Kindle with version 6.2.1_user_3103920

Answer (score 2):

[Rooting the Kindle Fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/how-do-i-root-my-kindle-fire) (necessary for installing a new system, see tutorials below)

[Installing CyanogenMod on the Kindle Fire](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-and-install-cyanogenmod-7-on-kindle-fire-how-to-tutorial/) (I guess it is pretty much the same with other Android systems)

[Installing the Android Market on the Kindle Fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/how-can-i-get-the-android-market-installed-on-my-kindle-fire) (may also be helpful)

**! Warning !**

**The Kindle Fire is known for having hardware compatibility issues with systems other than the pre-installed one!**

Comment: "Stock" usually refers to the ROM that ships with a device (as in, the ROM it was "stocked" with by the manufacturer). CyanogenMod would typically be referred to as "AOSP" or "Vanilla" Android.

Comment: I am sorry for this, it should be better now.

Comment: I updated two of your links to point to our local questions here, hopefully that's OK.  We want information to be as self-contained as possible and avoid link rot.