# Installing Fresh Android OS

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, amazon-kindle-fire

I have Amazon fire tablet. I want to install fresh android 4.4 or above. Is there any step by step instruction available somewhere or how do I do this?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying. A Factory reset? or a new version?

Comment: My tablet running Amazon Fire OS. If I do factory reset then again I'll get Fire OS - I don't want this and instead of Fire OS I am interested in Pure Android OS either 4.4 or above

Comment: Check this thread out it might be a good starting place. There is a video in the second post.  You will need a custom recovery to flash a ROM. http://forum.xda-developers.com/amazon-fire/orig-development/twrp-recovery-t3242548

Comment: Yes, instructions are available: [How can I install vanilla Android on the Kindle Fire?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17482/16575). Tough those are for ICS and JB, the link for CM10/JB now leads to CM11/KK. Also see our [kindle-fire tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle-fire) for other related questions.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know which OS your tablet is running before you do anything. These tablets normally run Amazon Fire OS.

Amazon wanted to create its own operating system for its tablets. Rather than starting from scratch, Amazon takes that Android AOSP code and modified it to create “Fire OS.

But you can try your luck here..[XDA Amazon Fire Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/amazon-fire)

Comment: Yes Its running Amazon Fire OS, I'll try this link and update here